# How do I implement against AWS Timestream REST API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

Does anyone have a working example where they've integrated against AWS Timestream's REST API? I'm looking at the query endpoint. [Their documentation seems incomplete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/Using-API.endpoint-discovery.describe-endpoints.implementation.html#Using-API.endpoint-discovery.describe-endpoints.usage-notes). It says integrating against their REST API is possible but there isn't much more information than that. I've also searched on Google and in their sample repo etc but I'm not able to find anything.